# iDangero.us Swiper - dealing with large image sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, swiper.js

In my template, I genereate the iDangero.us "Swiper" slideshow:

```
<body>
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="..."></div>
<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="..."></div>
<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="..."></div>
... (image n)
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
  // initialize swiper
})
</script>
</body>
```

This works, however when I'm loading approximately 100 images (for about 5MB total of image data), it can take as much as 15 seconds for the slideshow to "snap to attention" (so to speak). Until then it stacks the images one on top of the other (as they all load). Once they are loaded, then it works fine. I'd like for it to remain "collapsed", even as the images are loading.

Is there a way to do this in the initialization code for Swiper? Also - is there an alternative way to do it just using javascript/css?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you want to do lazy loading, but I am not familiar with that library, can you check if the image is loaded or not ? toggle it with jquery toggle

Answer (score 0):

Give imagesLoaded a try (https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded). Listen to the done/always event and then initialize your swiper.

```
imagesLoaded(".swiper-wrapper").on("done", function() {
    // Initialize swiper
});
```